# Simple reggression with statsmodels - fit() error

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

On some data this code works, on sam not. What is the problem? I really don't uderstand:

```py
m1 = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula="y ~ x", data=mydata.dropna().reset_index())
m1f = m1.fit()
m1f.summary() # ERROR ! And sometimes FINE.
```

The error says: `ValueError: shapes (3672,2373) and (3672,2373) not aligned: 2373 (dim 1) != 3672 (dim 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `y`. It was character. After making it float it works, but now I have problem with:

```
m1.predict(mydata.dropna().reset_index())
```

> ValueError: shapes (5088,8) and (5089,7) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 5089 (dim 0)